# Why does my .NET webmethod return a complete HTML document instead of just the return value?

Tags: c#, javascript, web-services

I'm trying to get more familiar with AJAX, and web services, so I have created the simplest of webservices with VS2008, hello world, with a webmethod GetPaper, and am trying to get the return value "hello world".

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" Class="HelloWorld" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")] [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)] [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] public class 

HelloWorld  : System.Web.Services.WebService {
    [WebMethod]
    public string GetPaper() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

http://www.linkedpapers.com/helloworld.asmx

However, when I consume this webservice with Javascript, I get a complete HTML page as a result, not just the value!

```
xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = ApplyUpdate;
xmlRequest.open("GET", "http://www.linkedpapers.com/helloworld.asmx?op=GetPaper", true);
xmlRequest.send();
```

It's probably very simple, but I just can't seem to figure it out! Help is very much appreciated.

Regards,

Heras

edit: Or do I use a wrong URL? If so, what should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be more like this:

```
xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = ApplyUpdate;
xmlRequest.open("GET", "http://www.linkedpapers.com/helloworld.asmx/GetPaper", true);
xmlRequest.send();
```

Also make sure you configure your web.config to allow the GET action:

```
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name=”HttpGet”/>
  </protocols>
</webServices>
```

Comment: Yes! That combination did the trick!

I tried "helloworld.asmx/GetPaper" but that doesn't work without "add name=HttpGet" in the web.config.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at using a web reference in an ASP.NET scriptmanager instead of the basic GET request.  This article should help you with that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163499.aspx

Comment: Thank you for sharing that link, and sure, eventually I want to use .NET supporting AJAX functionality, but before I set off to start creating a more complex web application, I really want to learn the basics, what's really happening, and I immediately get stuck at the simplest task...

I'm definitely going to dive into your link, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe HTTP GET and POST are disabled by default. ["INFO: HTTP GET and HTTP POST Are Disabled by Default"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819267)

Comment: Thanks! I will add both Get and Post to the web.config, to make sure I won't run into the same trouble in the future again.